# Bootstrap 4: hidden-md-up not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to hide these menu bars with the class hidden-md-up, but it's not working. I'm using CDN but i've also tried the files and checked the class...can anyone help? Here's what I have

```
 <div class="col hidden-md-up">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x " aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities)

> **Removed from v4 alphas:** .hidden-xs-up .hidden-xs-down .hidden-sm-up
>   .hidden-sm-down .hidden-md-up .hidden-md-down .hidden-lg-up
>   .hidden-lg-down